# Adding to ArrayList issues

Tags: java, arraylist

I am prompting the user to enter their name as well as adding an ai player to my ArrayList. Unfortunately, I am receiving a "cannot find symbol" error on the words "add" in my code below. I am assuming it's something along the lines of not importing something, I can't seem to quite figure it out at the moment.

```
package connectfour;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import userInterface.Connect4Ui;
import core.Player;
import core.HumanPlayer;
import core.AiPlayer;


/**
 *
 * @author j_ortiz9688
 */

// connect 4 main 
public class ConnectFour {

    private static ArrayList<Player>player;
    private static Connect4Ui frame; 

    public static void makePlayers(){

        player = new ArrayList<Player>();

        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");

        HumanPlayer player = new HumanPlayer(name);


        AiPlayer ai = new AiPlayer("Computer", 0); 

        player.add(player); 
        player.add(ai);

    }



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame = new Connect4Ui(); 

    }

}
```

Comment: You really should name ArrayList and HumanPlayer variable the same.

Comment: HumanPlayer is a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new variable with the same name as the `ArrayList`, which hides the static `ArrayList` field in the class (It won't compile even if you remove the calls to `.add()`). You will need to rename either the local `player` variable or the `player` field.

For example:

```
    HumanPlayer humanPlayer = new HumanPlayer(name); // Renamed
    AiPlayer aiPlayer = new AiPlayer("Computer", 0); 

    player.add(humanPlayer); 
    player.add(aiPlayer);
```

Answer (score 2):

You define a local variable `HumanPlayer player = new HumanPlayer(name);` that **hides** your `ArrayList` datamember of the same name. Just give it a different name, and you should be OK:

```
HumanPlayer human = new HumanPlayer(name); // Here!
AiPlayer ai = new AiPlayer("Computer", 0); 

player.add(human);  // and use it here, of course
player.add(ai);
```

Comment: Yikes, dumb mistake on my behalf, thank you, this makes a lot more sense now. Thank you.